# Can't add an PresentationCore assembly to Win Phone 8.1 project

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a UWP project in VS 2015, I would like to use SolidColorBrush and initialize it with a Color. Color seems to be undefined. On MSDN it says it's in a System.Drawing namespace. But that namespace doesn't exist for me. MSDN says that namespace is in PresentationCore.DLL, but when I try to reference that DLL through Add->Reference->Frameworks it's just a blank page that says all assemblies already referenced. Is this a desktop only framework or something? Is there some other definition of Color in some other namespace that I'm aware of?

Comment: [Color](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.color) is in namespace `Windows.UI`.

Comment: Thank you @IInspectable I don't know why they have so many different definitions for this thing.

Comment: @TimAkgayev if you just got started with .NET, it would be a surprise. But consider the facts that Microsoft has WinForms, WPF, Silverlight, UWP, and XNA, it is not surprising at all that for the same thing there are multiple implementations. When searching on MSDN make sure you are looking at the correct section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous types called `Color` in different library implementations. The [System.Drawing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx) namespace is applicable, when targeting .NET Desktop.

Since you are using a [SolidColorBrush](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br242962) for the UWP, you'll want to use the [Color](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.color) type defined in the [Windows.UI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.aspx) namespace. When looking for documentation, make sure to include the search term *"UWP"*.